# Is it possible to add a custom Cloud file service (like OneDrive/Dropbox) to Outlook.com (Office 365)

Tags: outlook-addin

I've seen that when you add an Attachment in Outlook, you can automaticly add an attachment from a cloud service.

[image: OutlookScreenshoot]

Is there a possible way to add a custom entry to this list?

Answer (score 0):

I offer to you to use [OneDrive file picker](https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v7/js-picker-overview.htm) , with this you can simply add button to your add-in html and then it's open the log-in page and after user is log-in he could choose the files from one drive.

The steps wrote in the link but I write the main steps here:

1.register your app in  [Microsoft Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) .

2.Add the js refrence in your js file of your add-in:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.live.net/v7.0/OneDrive.js">
    </script>
```

3.Add button to your add-in html page:

```
    <button  class="oneDriveButton"  id="btnOneDrive" ><img src="https://js.live.net/v5.0/images/SkyDrivePicker/SkyDriveIcon_white.png" style="margin-right: 10px; height: 20px;">Open from OneDrive</button>
```

4.In your js file of add-in open the picker:

```
    $('#btnOneDrive').click(function () {
      var odOptions = {
        clientId: "your client id from your app registration  ",
        action: "download",
        multiSelect: true,
        openInNewWindow: true,
        linkType: "query",
        advanced: { redirectUri: "your redirect uri from app registration" },
        success: function (files) {
        },   
        cancel: function () { /* cancel handler */ 
        },
        error: function (e) { /* error handler */
        }
    };
    OneDrive.open(odOptions); });
```

Put attention:

- Your *clientId* and your *redirectUri* **must** be equal to this you
  set when you register your app in the first step.
- You could change the option by what you want ,look [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v7/js-picker-open.htm) under
  picker options .

Thats all , you get the files in sucess handler function and you could do whatever you want with them.

Good luck!

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood your answer, but I dont want to use Onedrive, I want to add our custom cloud web storage to the Outlook.com attachment dialog. Just like OneDrive and Google Drive are there. So We can directly select a file from the add Attachment dialog.

Comment: @lokimidgard Sorry so I don't understand right your question. You want to add your cloud service from the built attachment window of outlook ? I think that it's not possible to add something to there like you cant control for example the action of click of 'send' button...